# Python: How to add three text files into one variable and then split it into a list

Tags: python, string, file, concatenation, split

I'm using Python 2.5 and trying to make a variable called total and adding three files to it. Then i compress total and convert it into hex and split it into a list of strings with maximum length of 4096 characters.

Currently I have a list of the files and i'm concatenating it all to total in this way

```
filelist = ['debug.log', 'error.log', 'reclog.log'];
total = ''
for files in filelist:
    f = open(files, 'r');
    total = total + f.read();
    f.close();
compressedtotal = zlib.compress(total);
hextotal = compressedtotal.encode('hex');
```

Upto here I feel i did it efficiently. But then i try to split hextotal into a list of strings called msglist. But the maximum length of each string in msglist should be no more than 4096 characters long.

```
if len(hextotal)%4096 >0 : checker = 1;
else: checker = 0;
nmsgs = int(math.ceil(len(hextotal)/4096));
nn = str(nmsgs);
msglist = [];
for msgs in range(1,nmsgs+1):
    if msgs == nmsgs and checker == 1:
        msglist.append(hextotal[4096*(msgs-1):]);
    else: msglist.append(hextotal[4096*(msgs-1):4096*(msgs)]);
```

There should me a more simpler way because this isnt "pythonic" and im quite new to python.
THanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite is a list comprehension:

```
msglist = [ hextotal[i:i+4096] for i in range(0,len(hextotal),4096) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
msglist = []
for start in range(0, len(hextotal), 4096):
    msglist.append(hextotal[start:start+4096])
```

You can slice beyond the end of something; it'll automatically just give you only up to the end of the string (for instance, slicing `"abcd"[2:6]` will give you `cd`).

As CSkau pointed out, this can also be done in list comprehension form:

```
msglist = [hextotal[i:i+4096] for i in range(0, len(hextotal), 4096)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a generator that returns chunks:

```
def chunkify(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

Then you could either iterate over the chunks

```
msglist = []
for chunk in chunkify(hextotal, 4096):
    msglist.append(chunk)
```

or create the final list like so

```
msglist = list(chunkify(hextotal, 4096))
```

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- No need for semicolons at end line endings
- No need to build a generator or compute upward rounded numbers of chunks
- Avoid using += to build-up long strings

Instead, let slicing and list comprehensions do the work for you:

```
filelist = ['debug.log', 'error.log', 'reclog.log'];
total = [open(filename, 'r').read() for filename in filelist]
compressedtotal = zlib.compress(''.join(total))
hextotal = compressedtotal.encode('hex')
msglist = [hextotal[i:i+4096] for i in range(0, len(hextotal), 4096)]
```